# strange behaviour with glossaries and setacronymstyle

Tags: glossaries

I have several cross-refences of acronyms within my thesis, where I would like to include both abbreviations.

The following MWE however produces strange output. Note, that the abbreviation is (PCI) instead of (PXI):

```
PCI eXtensions for Instrumentation (PCI) is a specific communication bus.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{glossaries}

%   on first use, display the long form with the short form in parentheses
%   (this is also the default behavior)
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PCI}{PCI}{Peripheral Component Interconnect}
\newacronym{PXI}{PXI}{\acrshort{PCI} eXtensions for Instrumentation}

\begin{document}

\gls{PXI} is a specific communication bus.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

When I leave out the `\setacronymstyle`, the text is rendered with the correct abbreviation:

```
PCI eXtensions for Instrumentation (PXI) is a specific communication bus.
```

Since those are acronyms, I prefer not to use the `see` tag that are possible for glossaries.

Can I somehow use `setacronymstyle` with the text correctly rendered?

Just in case, I'm using:

```
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
scrreprt 2015/10/03 v3.19a
glossaries 4.18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some strange interaction between the acronym rendering; it seems to be solved if you put the `\acrshort` instruction in braces.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{glossaries}

%   on first use, display the long form with the short form in parentheses
%   (this is also the default behavior)
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PCI}{PCI}{Peripheral Component Interconnect}
\newacronym{PXI}{PXI}{{\acrshort{PCI}} eXtensions for Instrumentation}

\begin{document}

\gls{PCI} is the original. Again \gls{PCI}.

\gls{PXI} is a specific communication bus. Again \gls{PXI}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]